# ES6 `export * from import`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a syntax using ES6 or ES7 or babel which will allow me to easily bundle together many groups of sub files?

E.g., given:

```
./action_creators/index.js
./action_creators/foo_actions.js
./action_creators/bar_actions.js
```

Have index.js import foo and bar actions, then re-export them, so I can

```
import {FooAction, BarAction} from './action_creators/index.js'
```

I don't want to have to remember / change references if I were to change which file I've organized the objects themselves into.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Yes, **ES6 supports directly exporting imported modules**:

```
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;

export {FooAction, BarAction} from './action_creators/index.js'
```

---

You can also **re-export all exports** of the imported module using the `*` syntax:

```
export * from …;

export * from './action_creators/index.js';
```

---

[More info on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139740/how-to-re-export-another-modules-default-export?noredirect=1&lq=1) worked for me `export { default as foo } from './foo';` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work `export * as something from './something'`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Qwerty you cannot currently export as named namespaces like that. See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from for the proposal for it.

One thing you can do in the meantime is something like:

```
import * as Something from './something';
export { Something }
```

Comment: What happens if two subsequent lines of `export * from ...` export a named function with the same name? I mean, if `export * from 'a';` and `export * from 'b'`, both `a` and `b` define a function with the same name and export it, e.g.: `export function fn() { ... }`...

Comment: I came here looking for why I can't use `export * as something from ...`.... Hahahhh

Comment: @Qwerty Same . . .

Comment: Guys you can also do `export * as default from './some-module';`

Comment: @tonix If there are two wildcard exports statements that implicitly re-export the same name, neither one is re-exported.

Answer (score 77):

**Default** export as **Default**:

```
export {default} from './something';
```

**Default** export as **Named**:

```
export {default as foo} from './something';
```

**Named** export as **Default**:

```
export {foo as default} from './something';
```

**Named** export as **Named**:

```
export {foo} from './something';
```

**Named** export as **Renamed**:

```
export {foo as bar} from './something';
```

**All** export **as is**:

```
export * from './something';
```

Comment: How about `export * from './something';`

Comment: **All Named** exports as all **Named**

Comment: `export *` does not export the `default` actually, it's mot like @skube phrased it

Answer (score 0):

```
export * from './something';
export {default} from './something';
```

can export default and others