# How to re-export another module's default export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to export some module like below way but always failed..

**foo.js**

```
const foo = {
  a: 'b'
};
export default foo;
```

**index.js**

```
export foo from './foo';  // encounter error here
export * from './foo';    // it works..
```

I don't know why can't I use the first method to export module from `foo.js`, in my opinion, I can export anything like func, class, variables etc..

Comment: @vsync  I'm so sorry, I'll change the title as soon as possible, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @vsync  thanks again,  it's my mistake :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To export a default export of one module as a named export of another you must do:

```
// index.js
export { default as foo } from './foo';
```

You can now import `foo` as a named export elsewhere:

```
// another.js
import { foo } from './index'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Comment: Although I understand the example, I'd like to know if there's any reason for the curly braces here. Why is not possible the following (without using Babel)?
`export default from './foo';` (in _index.js_) and then import it as `import myDefault from './index.js' ` (in _another.js_)