# How to arrange action creators in a react-redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to React & Redux and all this while, I'm putting all my action creators & my constants into a single file '../actions/index.js'.
When I started out, this seemed fine but now, it's become this huge block of unreadable code.

Would you suggest breaking down index.js into functionality1.js, func2.js, func3.js and then importing actions as needed from split up files:

```
import {sampleAction} from '../action/func1';
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Sorry if this seems like a silly question. I'm still trying to understand best practices in a React-Redux application.

Comment: Not a silly question at all. You may prefer this kind of structure instead: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still split it up but retain the `index.js` for simplicity using the [`export * from '...'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077264/6902543) syntax.

actions/functionality1.js:

```
export const ACTION_1 = '...'
export const ACTION_2 = '...'

export const action1 = () => {...}
export const action2 = () => {...}
```

actions/functionality2.js:

```
export const ACTION_3 = '...'
export const ACTION_4 = '...'

export const action3 = () => {...}
export const action4 = () => {...}
```

actions/index.js:

```
export * from './functionality1'
export * from './functionality2'
```

Then you can import any you need like so:

```
import { action1, action4, ACTION_2, ACTION_3 } from './actions'
```

Comment: That's really neat, thanks! Could/should I do the same for containers/components?

Comment: There's no reason you can't use this trick throughout your entire app.  I often use it break up logical sections of functionality.  For example all the the component, containers, action, action types and reducers for login would be seperated into a `Login` folder with an `index.js` exporting each of the pieces.