# npm react module error

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, components

I am currently trying to build a react component library.

I have [this](https://github.com/garritfra/satirical-ui) project set up, but when i try to include it in a demo project, i get the following error:

> Invariant Violation
>
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of 'App'.

My index.js:

```js
import Button from "./components/Button";

export default {
  Button
};
```

my sample component

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
const Button = styled.button`
  background: #1FB6FF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  &:hover {
    background: #009EEB;
  }
`;
export default Button;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

can anyone tell where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I linked the github project in the description because i think the issue might be related to not just the main file

Comment: Cool, post your code. Also that GitHub project doesn't even have an App.js file.

Comment: it has an index.js

Comment: `export default { Button }` should be: `export default Button`.

Comment: isn't that a problem once i add more components?

Comment: No, you can only default export one thing. When you've many components it won't be default anymore. Also, in `index.js` you can do something like: `export  * from ./Button1.js`,  `export  * from ./Button2.js`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `export default { Button }` should be: `export default Button`.

Comment: and where are your rendering to HTML?

Comment: am i supposed to?

Comment: What? You're not rendering your components anywhere, e.g. an App.js file with `ReactDOM.render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In your index.js file instead of

```
export * from "./components/Button";
```

do this

```
export Button from "./components/Button";
```

and

`export default { Button }`

should be:

`export default Button.`

For more info refer this [ES6 `export * from import`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077164/es6-export-from-import)