# How to spread into export

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript file where I simply define the css classes so I can use them through out my code and can maintain them in one place, like this:

```js
//css.js

const pre = 'grc-';

const backdropcss = {
  backdrop: `${pre}backdrop`,
};
const buttoncss = {
  btn: `${pre}btn`,
  btnSm: `${pre}btn--sm`,
  btnSecondary: `${pre}btn--secondary`,
  btnTertiary: `${pre}btn--tertiary`,
  btnLink: `${pre}btn--link`,
  btnFull: `${pre}btn--full`,
  btnHalf: `${pre}btn--half`,
  btnThird: `${pre}btn--third`,
};

//etc.
```

I am using it in two ways. For my component library I like to isolate the css names for the components like this:

```js
export {
  buttoncss,
  alertcss,
  checkboxcss,
  formcss,
  radioboxcss,
  drawercss,
  backdropcss,
  rangecss,
};
```

So I can import only what I need.
But I also want a default export where all the definitions are combined. 
 (Note: so I **don't** want to use them as `cssjs.buttoncss` but rather as `cssjs` which has all the sub objects spread into)

To create the object I spread all the sub objects and then I export it as default, like this:

```js
const cssjs = {
  ...buttoncss,
  ...alertcss,
  ...checkboxcss,
  ...formcss,
  ...radioboxcss,
  ...drawercss,
  ...backdropcss,
  ...rangecss,
};

export default cssjs;
```

Now, every time I create a new components it feels redundant to add it twice in those objects. So I wanted to create an `all` object:

```js
const all = {
  buttoncss,
  alertcss,
  checkboxcss,
  formcss,
  radioboxcss,
  drawercss,
  backdropcss,
  rangecss,
};
```

And spread them into the (named) export(s):

```js
export { ...all}
```

Then I'll write some code to loop through the `all` object and spread every sub object into one big object (to create the `cssjs` object from before).

But before I was able to write that last code I noticed that the `export { ...all}` syntax was not supported. Is there any way to accomplish what I want, or do I have to write everything twice like I do now?

---

EDIT:

Re-using variables if you set them as exports when declaring threw me off guard. This my code now:

```js
//more definitions

export const formcss = {
  formGroup: `${pre}form--group`,
};

export const radioboxcss = {
  radio: `${pre}radio`,
  radioStacked: `${pre}radio--stacked`,
};

export default {
  ...buttoncss,
  ...alertcss,
  ...checkboxcss,
  ...formcss,
  ...radioboxcss,
  ...drawercss,
  ...backdropcss,
  ...rangecss,
};
```

This solved my particular question, but still makes me wonder why it's not possible to spread an object into an export declaration so you can export everything in the object as named within the object. So for other people who might come here through the title:

Why can I do this

```js
const one = 1
const two = 2

export { one, two, }
```

But not this

```js
const one = 1
const two = 2 
const numbers = { one, two, }

export { ...numbers, }
```

Comment: This maybe is the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077264/2469567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless I'm missing something, you don't need to spread `all` into a new object to get that to work, just `export all`
2. It sounds like what you really want is just normal named exports. Instead of combining everything into one object, you can just say `export const buttoncss = ...` and skip all of this entirely

Comment: `1.` is not what I meant, but `2.` made me feel stupid, because that is what I need. I guess combining them afterwards for a default export threw me off guard, so I didn't think of exporting all the objects when declaring them. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Exports are not an object, even if shorthand named export syntax looks very similar to shorthand object literal syntax. So no, there is indeed no way to use spread syntax there, which also would imply dynamic export names.

> Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

After using named exports for all your individual styles, you could import your own module as a namespace:

```
import * as myself from './css.js';
```

Then `myself` will be a namespace object containing all the exported names. You could now `default`-export something that uses this object:

```
const all = {};
for (const p in myself)
    if (p != "default")
        Object.assign(all, myself[p]);
export { all as default };
```

Make sure to put this code in the end of your module, so that `myself[p]` will evaluate to an already initialised variable.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive, I did not know you could self import.