# Not a function error for an npm package using export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I published an npm package. The directory structure is something like the following:

```
my-package
└── js/script.js
└── index.js
```

The `js/script.js` file contains an object that is the name of my library, lets say `elephant`. Something like this:

```
var elephant = {
    function_1: function() {
        ...
    },
    function_2: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my `index.js` file, I am exporting this like so:

```
import { elephant } from "./js/script.js";

export default elephant;
```

Once I published and installed my package, I tried to use it in my project using the following lines of code:

```
const elephant = require('my-package');
elephant.function_1();
elephant.function_2();
```

However, unfortunately when I run my dev server (in a Vue project), I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: elephant.function_1 is not a function"
```

What am I doing wrong? The function has been clearly defined, and the export works, but the function is not detected. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you forget to add `export` to `var elephant = ` in `js/script.js`

Comment: @RPasha So I just add `export` before the `var elephant`? Could you explain a bit more on this?

Comment: can you share your package so we can test? also, in your project you are using `ES import module ` syntax, and then in your sample you use  `commonjs` i.d. `requiere` syntax. try using `module.exports.elephant  = {......}` in your `js/script.js` and `module.exports = require("./js/script.js")` in your `index.js`

Comment: This time, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: elephant is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if it works here or not, but I use this syntax which works pretty well. You may try it on dev server. This is for `index.js`.

```
export {
    elephant
} from './js/script.js';
```

Export your `elephant` from `js/script.js`

```
var elephant = {
    function_1: function() {
        ...
    },
    function_2: function() {
        ...
    }
}

export default elephant;
```

In case of ES5 and older javascript version, use this syntax rather:

`module.exports = elephant;`

Comment: Please export your `elephant`.

Comment: I tried your edited answer, but unfortunately still get the same error :(

Comment: Okay After adding export default to `elephant` in `js/script.js`. Just try this syntax in `index.js`: `export {default} from './js/script.js';`. Here `default` represents `elephant`. You can look for more references here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960891/13192834). Will update the answer once it works.